# Using localstorage data instead $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, local-storage, gridster, angular-local-storage

Are there any means of using what is initially stored in the localStorage (https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) instead of using $scope.whatever? I am having a hard time retrieving what is initially stored into my $scope.whatever JSON object after I transferred it to localStorage. Maybe there are some solutions you know to solve this.

I am currently working on saving data from $scope.whatever to a localStorage but one problem I encountered is that when I get to refresh the page where my javascript code is running on I get to have a null on my $scope.dashboard and could not take the localStorage value. My Controller below:

```
function($scope, $timeout, $sce, localStorageService) {
    var lsLength = localStorageService.length();
    var lsKeys = localStorageService.keys();

    $scope.gridsterOptions = {
        margins : [20, 20],
        columns : 4,
        draggable : {
            handle : 'h4',
            stop : function(event, $element, widget) {

                if (lsLength == 0) {

                    localStorageService.set('widgets', $scope.dashboards[1]);
                } ** else {
                    localStorageService.set('widgets', $scope.dashboards[1]);
                } **

            }
        }
    };

    if (localStorageService.get('widgets') == null) {

        $scope.dashboards = {
            '1' : {
                id : '1',
                widgets : [{
                    code : "urlfilter-widget.html",
                    col : 0,
                    row : 0,
                    sizeY : 1,
                    sizeX : 2,
                    title : "URL Filter"
                }, {
                    code : "systemdash-widget.html",
                    col : 2,
                    row : 0,
                    sizeY : 2,
                    sizeX : 2,
                    title : "System Information"
                }, {
                    code : "device-widget.html",
                    col : 0,
                    row : 4,
                    sizeY : 1.5,
                    sizeX : 2,
                    title : "Device Clock"
                }, {
                    code : "cpupercentage-widget.html",
                    col : 2,
                    row : 4,
                    sizeY : 1,
                    sizeX : 2,
                    title : "CPU Percentage Usage"
                }, {
                    code : "memorypercentage-widget.html",
                    col : 0,
                    row : 6,
                    sizeY : 1,
                    sizeX : 2,
                    title : "Memory Percentage Usage"
                }, {
                    code : "proxyantivirusstatistics-widget.html",
                    col : 2,
                    row : 6,
                    sizeY : 1,
                    sizeX : 2,
                    title : "Proxy Antivirus Statistics"
                }, {
                    code : "firewallconnections-widget.html",
                    col : 0,
                    row : 8,
                    sizeY : 1,
                    sizeX : 2,
                    title : "Firewall Active Connections"
                }, {
                    code : "dpi-widget.html",
                    col : 2,
                    row : 8,
                    sizeY : 2,
                    sizeX : 2,
                    title : "Deep Packet Inspection"
                }, {
                    code : "toptendpichart-widget.html",
                    col : 0,
                    row : 10,
                    sizeY : 2,
                    sizeX : 2,
                    title : "Top 10 DPI Chart"
                }, {
                    code : "toptenurlfilter-widget.html",
                    col : 2,
                    row : 10,
                    sizeY : 2,
                    sizeX : 2,
                    title : "Top 10 URL Filter"
                }, {
                    code : "firewallgraph-widget.html",
                    col : 0,
                    row : 12,
                    sizeY : 1,
                    sizeX : 2,
                    title : "Firewall Connections"
                }]
            }
        };
    } else {
        $scope.dashboards = localStorageService.get(key);
    }
    // init dashboard
    for ( x = 0; x <= lsLength; x++) {
        var key = lsKeys[x];
        if (lsKeys == key) {
            $scope.dashboard = localStorageService.get(key);
            break;
        } else {
            $scope.dashboard = $scope.dashboards[1];
        }
    }
    $scope.clear = function() {
        $scope.dashboard.widgets = [];
    };

    $scope.addWidget = function() {
        $scope.dashboard.widgets.push({
            name : "New Widget",
            sizeX : 1,
            sizeY : 1
        });
    };
    $scope.watch('dashboards[1].widgets', function() {
    }, true);
}]).controller('CustomWidgetCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal',
function($scope, $modal) {

    $scope.remove = function(widget) {
        $scope.dashboard.widgets.splice($scope.dashboard.widgets.indexOf(widget), 1);
    };

    $scope.openSettings = function(widget) {
        $modal.open({
            scope : $scope,
            templateUrl : 'demo/dashboard/widget_settings.html',
            controller : 'WidgetSettingsCtrl',
            resolve : {
                widget : function() {
                    return widget;
                }
            }
        });
    };

}])
```

I'm having an error on the else statement (below) because stop reads $scope.dashboards == null;

```
 ** else {
                        localStorageService.set('widgets', $scope.dashboards[1]);
                    } **
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: This question is way too vague for anyone to answer. You can store data in localStorage and add it to `$scope` when your controller initializer runs. You just need to use `localStorage` correctly in the same way it would ever be used.

Comment: Are you loading your files locally or using a web server?

Comment: @AniketSinha, I tried both.

Comment: How do you set items in localStorage from `localStorageService`? 
Try `localStorage.setItem('test','123');console.log(localStorage.getItem('test'));`

Comment: Yes, I use localStorageService to set items to localStorage. Problem is, I couldn't take back the data from the scope.dashboards which holds the position of the widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see 2 flaws in your code.

1.

```
if (lsLength == 0) {
  localStorageService.set('widgets', $scope.dashboards[1]);
} else {
  localStorageService.set('widgets', $scope.dashboards[1]);
}
```

No matter if your condition is true or false, you are executing

`localStorageService.set('widgets', $scope.dashboards[1]);`.

Your code should be more or less like :

```
if (lsLength == 0) {
    localStorageService.set('widgets', $scope.dashboards[1]);
 }  else {
    localStorageService.get('widgets');
 }
```

2. in your `if (localStorageService.get('widgets') == null) {`  block, after assigning value of `$scope.dashboards`, you are not setting it in localStorage though you are correctly fetching from localStorage in `else` block.

Add `localStorageService.set('widgets',$scope.dashboards);` in your if block.

Try these and comment if something more is needed.